# Fastapi ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed

Tags: python, ssl, asynchronous, fastapi, uvicorn

I have the following code

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/index")
async def index(request: Request):
    return await google()

async def google():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://google.com') as response:
            return await response.text()

# print(asyncio.run(google()))
```

When I do a POST call to "/index" it is supposed to return the html of google.com but I get the error `ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed`

But when I call the coroutine directly (as seen in my last print) the aiohttp call works, it's just that it does not work when I call it from a route.

The code below fixes this, but why is this needed? It is not needed if I call this directly.

```
import certifi,ssl
sslcontext = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())


async with session.get('https://google.com', ssl=sslcontext)
```

Edit:
Versions `Python 3.10.0`, `fastapi 0.70.0`, `aiohttp 3.7.4.post0`

Edit 2:

Instead of doing `uvicorn main:app`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run('main:app')
```

doing this makes the error go away, but still the issue is when I run from the cli using `uvicorn main:app --reload`

"why do I have to do this? It works normally"